# Indent ExPex examples that are not numbered

Tags: spacing, indentation, linguistics, expex

[ExPex](https://ctan.org/pkg/expex) offers `\exdisplay` to create linguistic examples without numbers (usually in combination with `\noexno` to prevent the counter being incremented).

However, according to the [manual](https://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/generic/expex/expex-doc.pdf) (pg. 71), indenting examples via `\textoffset` is not possible with `\exdisplay`. Is there another way to get a 'default' indentation whenever `\exdisplay` is used? I've used `\hspace{}` repeatedly (per line) as a workaround, but it is cumbersome and also prevents the use of `\\` as a line break.

Here are some examples depicting the issue, the current workaround/desired output and the inability to use `textoffset`:

[image]

**Minimal Reproducible Example (MRE)**

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expex}

\begin{document}
\noindent
Example undesired output (note the lack of indent):
\exdisplay\noexno
John gave people homes\\
John gave homes people
\xe
Example desired output (indented):
\exdisplay\noexno
\hspace{4em}John gave people homes

\hspace{4em}John gave homes people
\xe
Using \texttt{textoffset} does not work:
\exdisplay[textoffset=4em]\noexno
John gave people homes\\
John gave homes people
\xe

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround is to use a phantom label with `exno`. In this case you also don't need to switch off the counter increment because a label defined with the `exno` argument does not change the counter.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expex}

\begin{document}
\noindent
Normal numbered example:
\ex
John gave people homes\\
John gave homes people
\xe
Example desired output (indented):
\ex[exno=\phantom{(X)},exnoformat=X]
John gave people homes\\
John gave homes people
\xe
Resume normal numbering:
\ex
John gave people homes\\
John gave homes people
\xe
\end{document}
```

If you want you can make the syntax a bit simpler by defining a macro:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expex}
\def\mydisplay{\ex[exno=\phantom{(X)},exnoformat=X]}
\begin{document}
% ...
\mydisplay
John gave people homes\\
John gave homes people
\xe
%...
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was after. The addition of the macro makes for a clean solution too.

Comment: @KyleF.Hartzenberg it's not very clean conceptually, with a fake invisible example number - it would have been nicer to actually have a real indent. However, given the small amount of code needed for this workaround and the large amount of digging in the package source code that would be required to implement a clean solution I guess this isn't too bad :)

Comment: Indeed! I was about to go delving, but you saved me the effort!